# Weird LDAP search results behaviour

Tags: active-directory, ldap, g-suite, query

I am building Google Directory sync from our domain to our Google apps account.
I am trying to search for all users in a specific Distribution Group: GoogleAppsActiveUsers.

I am using Windows 2003 R2 as our AD.

I have 1 user added to the group: GoogleAppsActiveUsers: user@test.com
that group is sub to the OU Company Users.
If my search criteria includes

```
CN=GoogleAppsActiveUsers,OU=Company Users,DC=company
```

In this case I get 0 results returned.

My Filter is:

```
(objectClass=person)
```

However, if I change my DN to be:

```
OU=Company Users,DC=company
```

As a result I get ALL my users (including the one within my GoogleAppsActiveUsers group.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The following DN: CN=GoogleAppsActiveUsers,OU=Security_Groups,OU=OptiTex_Users,DC=optitex and filter * gives me only the CN=GoogleAppsActiveUsers as a result. How do I get the users in that group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search results you specify are exactly as expected from the search parameters you give. `(objectClass=person)` with the base DN of `CN=GoogleAppsActiveUsers,OU=Company Users,DC=company`, assuming a search scope of `sub` (you did not specify what search scope you used), would filter all objects from the candidate list that contained the attribute `objectClass` with a value of `person` (or subtypes of `person`). In your case, there are no objects that match those criteria. When you widen the search to start at a higher level (`OU=Company Users,DC=company`), again assuming a search scope of `sub`, more entries are returned. It might be that you should change your filter to `(isMemberOf=CN=GoogleAppsActiveUsers,OU=Company Users,DC=company)` or `(memberOf=CN=GoogleAppsActiveUsers,OU=Company Users,DC=company)` in order to find the members of the desired group.

Comment: I get still weird answers. If I try with memberOf=CN=GoogleAppsActiveUsers,OU=Security_Groups,OU=company_Users,DC=company I get a null exception error [FATAL] [ui.page.SimulateSyncWorker$WorkerStatusLogger] Exception while attempting to retrieve results
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: : [LDAP: error code 34 - 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-031001BA, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8349, best match of:'memberOf=CN=GoogleAppsActiveUsers,OU=Security_Groups,OU=Company_Users,DC=company'

Comment: If I remove the memberof=CN=GoogleAppsActiveUsers I get a result that is too long (the one level above what I want.   I do use the Sub-Tree but I tried also level and one also

Comment: I think that the query is correct, but how do I make it work in the configuration manager of google directory sync? the base DN is correct, with the CN, but I think the rule needs some work.

Comment: Did you try `isMemberOf` instead of `memberOf`?

Comment: I did, same result. As I said, I think the tweak has to be in the filter. As the DN is correct, and should not include the memberOf/isMemberOf. That should be in the filter area of the configuration.

Comment: The `memberOf` and `isMemberOf` do not belong in the DN. The DN is the primary that identifies the entry. `memberOf` and `isMemberOf` are most likely not even real attributes, rather, they are probably virtual attributes or dynamic attributes. If you could post the LDIF of the `GoogleAppsActiveUsers` group, perhaps that would help.

Comment: Not sure on how to extract LDIF using AD explorer. If you can show me please.

Comment: I have never used AD Explorer, but from a quick look at the web page, it looks like a basic directory browser. Perhaps you can navigate in the left hand side down to your group entry and right-click or something to save the LDIF.

Comment: @Saariko let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/980/discussion-between-terry-gardner-and-saariko)

Comment: Thanks Ter for all your help, the answer was: E U R E K A !!!!!! 
Base DN:OU=OptiTex_Users,DC=optitex 
Filter: (memberof=CN=GoogleAppsActiveUsers,OU=Security_Groups,OU=OptiTex_Users,DC=optitex)